# How do I read T_SENSOR on Windows?

Tags: windows, temperature

I Just checked from my BIOS -> Monitoring -> Temperature Sensor, it reads 27C. This is the temp sensor of my water pump. I tried a bunch of different apps, HWMonitor seems to *almost* do the trick:

[image]

The user manual doesn't mention anything about AUXTIN. Which one is supposed to be T_SENSOR?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely your BIOS would interface with your water cooling’s temperature sensors.

Comment: @DanielB What do you mean? I plugged the temp sensor in the T_SENSOR header and it shows up in the BIOS.

Comment: This is an important fact that should be in your question, along with the exact make and model of all hardware involved.